# Using Magento for quotes in physical store

Tags: quote

How would it be possible to use Magento for quotes made in store by the store staff? You can create a new order in admin, but it reduces the stock right away when you make an order and that is not what we want. For quotes it's not needed to reduce the stock, because customer does not necessarily make a purchase.

We need to be able to make an offer quickly and print it to PDF with product images in the printed PDF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible solutions I know of.  First one does a PDF quote system which can be sent by email here: http://www.boostmyshop.com/english/extension-devis.html

The second is more functional but sends quotes out via email www.cart2quote.com/ your staff can either use a front end or back end system to operate this.

Both priced around the £300 mark.

Comment: I actually found the Boostmyshop's extension on my own too and that seems indeed a very good option. Just have to get those product images to the PDF, but I guess they might be able to modify the extension for me.